# Find out the saddle points from a given matrix using C

Tags: c

Detect saddle points in a matrix.

So say you have a matrix like so:

9  8  7

5  3  2

6  6  7

It has a saddle point at column 1, row 2 with value 5.

It's called a "saddle point" because it is greater than or equal to every element in its row and less than or equal to every element in its column.

A matrix may have zero or more saddle points.

Your code should be able to provide the (possibly empty) list of all the saddle points for any given matrix.

The matrix can have a different number of rows and columns (Non square).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int r,c;
int main()
{
    int mat;
    printf("Enter the row and the column number:\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
    int matrix[r][c];
    printf("Enter the elements of matrix:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("Matrix[%d][%d]:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
         mat = matrix[i][j];
         saddle(i,j,mat,matrix);
        }
    }
}
void saddle(int i,int j,int mat, int matrix[r][c])
{
    int c1=0,c2=0;
    for(int a=i;a<i+1;a++)
    {
        for(int b=0;b<c;b++)
        {
        if(mat>=matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j]==matrix[a][b])
            c1++;
        }
    }
    if(c1==(c-1))
    {
    for(int a=0;a<r;a++)
    {
        for(int b=j;b<j+1;b++)
        {
        if (mat<=matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j]==matrix[a][b])
            c2++;
        }
    }
    }
    if(c2==(r-1))
    printf("Saddle point at row %d, column %d, with value %d\n",i,j,mat);

}
```

I have completed the code and in my view its right but it is not giving the desired output. Please point the errors in my code and what changes i must do to get the correct output?

Comment: Per your definition of "saddle-point", your saddle function should only ever need to look at elements in row i or column j, but you're looking at other elements of the matrix which are irrelevant.

Comment: here's a src example with different min/max rules: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saddle-point-matrix/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change from `if (mat >= matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j] == matrix[a][b])` to `if (mat >= matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j] != matrix[a][b])`.
And you need to change from `if (mat <= matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j] == matrix[a][b])` to `if (mat <= matrix[a][b] && matrix[i][j] != matrix[a][b])`.

The problem was you checked if the number `mat` you passed is equal to himself, and it's always true so your counter `c1` was worng.